# Parse Android xml file instead of iOS .strings

Tags: android, iphone, string, localization

So as mobile developers, every time we translate one of our apps we have to translate both Android and iOS strings files. These files contain 90% of the same strings just the file is in a different format.

Does anyone know if there is an NSLocalizedString override to read from Android compatible .xml files? or if this is even possible?

Alternatively, is there a command line tool to convert between the two formats?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This does what you need, but not from the command line.
http://localise.biz/free/converter/ios-to-android

The full system has an API though. If you register you'll be able to pull your translations into `.strings` or Android XML files from the command line, or programmatically via a simple script.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out this kind of tool doesn't exist. I created a toolchain and posted it [here](https://github.com/paul-delange/cocolize.git).

If there is activity I will develop it further.

Answer (score 1):

For a recent project which already had 19 translations, I was also looking for a script to convert the XCode Localizable.strings files to Android Eclipse format.

I found convertLocalizable.rb but I can't work with ruby, so I've created a Javascript based on it, see link below. You have to cut and paste each file but it works great.

[Javascript XCode Localizable.strings and Android strings.xml convertor](http://members.home.nl/bas.de.reuver/files/stringsconvert.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple [script](https://gist.github.com/3217498) that will generate iOS Localizable.strings from Android strings.xml files.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Twine](https://github.com/ratana/android-ios-string-utils) - a robust project for converting resources.